# Ggplot scale_fill_manual with dynamic returned values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with multiple columns of factor type (with 5 levels:  Dark Green, Green, Orange, Yellow, Grey) although each contains different values as per the screenshot below.

[image]

I tried to define a function to make a bar chart with colors of the legend manually set by the values contained in the selected column like so

```
library(tidyverse)
make_graph <- function(df, col){
  data = select(df, group, col)
  G = data$group
  C = data$col
  tbl = prop.table(table(G, C))
  DF = data.frame(tbl) %>% filter(freq != 0)
ggplot(data, aes(x=G,y=Freq, fill=C)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + theme_minimal() +
 scale_fill_manual(values=c(?????), labels=c(?????))  # needs to be automatically filled with the values contained in the selected column
```

My question is: how can I set the parameters `values` and `labels` dynamically depending on the column provided to the function `make_graph`? For example, if I do this `make_graph(df, 'col_2')` it will display a graph of 3 bars with colors dark green, green and orange and values of legend are 'great', 'good' and 'ok'

PS: below is the result of the code provided by akrun where the legend values were not aligned with the colors (for example darkgreen should be labelled as 'great' instead of 'terrible')

[image]

Comment: @akrun, I don't know how to include the data in the question. Can we randomly generate the value columns with these strings: 'dark green', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow' and 'grey'? The labels will be based on the values contained in the column such that dark green = great, green = good, orange = ok, yellow = poor, grey = terrible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
make_graph <- function(df, col){
 keyval <- setNames(c("great", "good", "ok", "poor", "terrible"), 
      c("dark green", "green", "orange", "yellow", "grey"))
 fill_m <- keyval[df[[col]]]
df %>%
   select(group, all_of(col)) %>%
   count(across(everything())) %>%
   mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
   filter(n != 0) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = group, y = n, fill = .data[[col]])) +
     geom_bar(stat= "identity", position = "dodge") + 
     theme_minimal() +
     scale_fill_manual(values = names(fill_m), labels = fill_m)



}
```

-testing

```
make_graph(df1, "col_2")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), col_1 = c("dark green", "dark green", 
"dark green", "dark green"), col_2 = c("dark green", "green", 
"orange", "orange"), col_3 = c("green", "yellow", "dark green", 
"grey"), col_4 = c("grey", "dark green", "orange", "yellow"), 
    col_5 = c("dark green", "grey", "grey", "grey")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It's amazing you could come up with such a solution so fast. However, it didn't work properly if we selected col_3 for example (I included in the OP). Could you please enhance the code? Thanks